# Unable to add Java imports in KIE workbench (jBPM)

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm, kie-workbench

I am brand new to jBPM. I am using the jBPM KIE workbench. As you can see in the 2nd picture, I added in the necessary imports in the KIE external data objects section. Why am I getting the errors? Do I need to do something else with the imports?

I am getting a thrown error of:

```
[KBase: defaultKieBase]: Process Compilation error URL cannot be resolved to a type
URL cannot be resolved to a type
HttpURLConnection cannot be resolved to a type
HttpURLConnection cannot be resolved to a type
BufferedReader cannot be resolved to a type
BufferedReader cannot be resolved to a type
InputStreamReader cannot be resolved to a type
```

Java Code:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/users");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            content.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();

        System.out.println(content);
    }

    catch(Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

[image: Kie workbench]

[image: External data model]

Comment: Make a `WorkItemHandler` or better yet use the existing `Rest` WorkItemHandler to invoke an external rest API.

Comment: @K.Nicholas other than jBPM documentation, do you have any references on where to learn this technology? There doesn't seem to many resources for it. This a completely new technology for me.

Comment: I think if you search for "jbpm rest workitem handler" you will find a couple blogs. The process is sufficiently described in the jBPM documentation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in REST workitem should be a good starting point.

Create a project and add a BusinessProcess:

[image: New Business Process]

Then Add the built in Rest Workitem

[image: Add Built in Rest Workitem]

Then Open the Rest Workitem Properties and select the data assignments

[image: Select Rest workitem Data Assignments]

And enter values for the Rest Call

[image: And enter values for the Rest Call]

Comment: How do I add a header? More specifically, I need to be able to make this request: `curl -iX GET --url 196.172.216.72:8001 --header 'Host: pythonapp'`

Comment: Guess you will have to write your own. Check the blogs.

Comment: Okay last question.. how do you set target? It appears blank. I am just playing around with KIE workbench at the moment. My goal is to call a web service that returns a random number and increments it in another task. I have a global variable named `RANDOM_NUMBER` how do I set that value to the response of the service that I'm calling? I'll figure out the custom headers part out later.

Comment: It's show in the last pic of the above answer. The "Data Outputs and Assignments" target will have values in the drop-down but you have to create a global variable by adding them to the properties of the main process. So just click on the background and the properties will change and you will find the ability to define global variables that will then appear in the target drop-down. You can practice by making a UserTask -- the variables of the task will show up in a generated form and you can assign them to a global target.